# Java JNLP file generated by PHP showing block message

Tags: java, php, jnlp

I am trying to generate Java JNLP file by PHP. When it's invoked to start java blocked message popup. I have already added http://localhost as trusted site and the jar file is self-signed; don't what to run the application. Any help will be appreciated.

jnlp launh html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Print</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</h3>
        <form action="launch.php" method="get">
            <label>Printer Name: </label>
            <input name="printer" value="CutePDF Printer"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label>File URL: </label>
            <input name="url" value="http://dev.webstie.co.uk/print_test/print.pdf"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" value="Print" name="Print">Print</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JNLP (launch.php) file

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/x-java-jnlp-file'); ?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost/testjnlp/dist" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>TestJNLP</title>
        <vendor>Hasan</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>TestJNLP</description>
        <description kind="short">TestJNLP</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+"/>
        <jar href="TestJNLP.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="PrinterList">
        <argument><?php echo $_GET['printer']; ?></argument>
        <argument><?php echo $_GET['url']; ?></argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The message im getting is

[image]

Comment: Have you been in the Java Control Panel?

Comment: yes. already done all those settings ... still getting the message!!!

Comment: *"the jar file is self-signed"* I don't see the point. It will need to be signed with a valid certificate before distribution, so start now.